# How to pass data from Activity to already created Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

Lately i've been stuck! I have one Activity (not my MainActivity, I mean, it is not where I created this Fragment), and I need to pass some data. I've already tried to pass using Bundle, using getter, but the same issue appears: "Attempt to invoke virtual method {...} on a null object." at the line where I call the Bundle in the Fragment. I am new at this, so I'm sorry if this is a simple question and I didn't understand. Below the relevant parts of my code:

**On Activity (not the main activity):**

```
public void save(){
    myGoal = spinnerGoals.getSelectedItem().toString();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("goal", myGoal);
    GoalFragment goalFragment = new GoalFragment();
    goalFragment.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

**On Fragment (where I want to put this 'goal')**

```
private TextView goal;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_goal, container, false);
    goal = view.findViewById(R.id.myGoalText);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        final String myGoal = bundle.getString("goal");
        goal.setText(myGoal);
    }
    return view;
}
```

**On MainActivity (where I created the Fragments):**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment() )
            .commit();
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_goal:
                        selectedFragment = new GoalFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_info:
                        selectedFragment = new InfoFragment();
                        break;
                }

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment)
                        .commit();

                return true;
            }
};
```

Please, I've lost much time trying to solve this by myself hahaha. If anyone can help me, i'd appreciate that!

Comment: does your main activity start from the activity where you are trying to send data from ?

Comment: how is second activity started? does your main activity starts it?

Comment: The MainActivity starts the Activity where i want to send data from.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in Fragment which you want to receive data, then invoke the method in Activity.

Write this code in Activity :

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("goal", myGoal);
 fragmentObj.sendData(bundle);
```

write code in Fragment:

```
public void sendData(Bundle bundle){
      String myGoal = bundle.getString("goal");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Activity(not main activity) was created from your fragment, you could use

```
startActivityForResult()
```

method to receive data after the activity is ended, read about it more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

If that is not the case, you need to persist (in storage) the data using `Preferences` or `Room Database`